# Linq causes build error

Tags: c#, build, cruisecontrol.net, build-automation, nant

Im using NAnt and CCNet on our build server. Lately when i've been doing Local Deployment, i get build errors that seems to be connected to Linq, generics and delegates.

Here are the result:

```
[nant] C:\Test\buildfiles\build.build
 Buildfile: ..........
 Target framework: Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
 Target(s) specified: build

build:
   [csc] Compiling 192 files to 'C:\TEST\bin'.
   [resgen] Read in 78 resources from 'C:\Test\Resources'.
   [csc] c:\Test\src\randomfile.cs<10,10>: error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult><System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>>' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly
```

On my machine i can build with no problems (vs2010). Im using the latest NAnt 0.91b.

**Update:**

The project has target framework 3.5.
Beneath is the code that generates the error (return section in first method):

```
public static RoleTypeIdAndName[] TranslateRoleTypes(RoleType[] roleTypes)
{
    return roleTypes.Select(TranslateRoleType).ToArray();
}

public static RoleTypeIdAndName TranslateRoleType(RoleType roleType)
{
    return new RoleTypeIdAndName
            {
                Name = roleType.Name,
                RoleTypeId = roleType.RoleTypeId
            };
}
```

Comment: You will definitely, definitely, definitely have to include the code when asking about a compile error

Comment: You say you're using VS2010 - does that mean you're targetting .NET 4 locally and 3.5 on the CCNet server?

Comment: are you using the right path for MSBuild.exe (.NET 3.5 vs. .NET 4.0) in that cc task?

Comment: It compiles with 3.5 both locally and on CCNet server. I've tried compiling with 4.0 just for sake of it. I've updated the post with some code that i forgot to paste...:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use vs2010 you need to set it to target framework 4.0 in the nant script or you can directly call the correct version (4.0) of msbuild and pass in your solution file.

Our current build script does it like that:

```
<target name="msbuild" depends="create.common.assembly.info">
    <echo message="Compiling ${msbuild.workingpath}\${solution.path}"/>
    <echo message="Build base path ${msbuild.path}"/>

    <exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuild.path}" workingdir="${msbuild.workingpath}">
      <arg value="/p:Configuration=${project.configuration}" />
      <arg value="/v:q" />
      <arg value="/p:trackfileaccess=false" />
      <arg value="/t:Clean"/>
      <arg value="${solution.path}"/>
    </exec>

    <exec program="msbuild.exe" basedir="${msbuild.path}" workingdir="${msbuild.workingpath}">
      <arg value="/p:Configuration=${project.configuration}" />      
      <arg value="/v:q" />
      <arg value="/p:trackfileaccess=false" />
      <arg value="/t:Rebuild"/>
      <arg value="${solution.path}"/>
    </exec>
    <property name="msbuild.output.file" value="${msbuild.workingpath}/msbuild-output.xml"/>
    <move if="${file::exists(msbuild.output.file)}" file="${msbuild.output.file}" todir="${log.path}" failonerror="false" overwrite="true" />
  </target>
```

Where the `${msbuild.path}` is `<property name="msbuild.path" value="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" />`

Comment: If i set the target framework to 4.0, NAnt seems to be using dll:s from 4.0 and causing the build to fail, due to 3.5 vs 4.0-differences.

Comment: @Mattias I had a similar issue with nant and the msbuild task. That's why I moved to use the exec task and I pass in the msbuild parameters by hand. This way you will have more control. In my current build script I don't even specify the framework.

Comment: How do you get NAnt to use this instead of the normal <nant target name="build">? I think thats the syntax being used.

Comment: Instead of using the msbuild task you just depend on this target `<target name="name" depends="build" ></target>` or call it directly by doing `nant build`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, I would guess it is one of the situations mentioned on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxfhx4sy(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: What justified the down vote, Holmes? There was no code posted when I replied. ???